# Basic Django Search Implementation

Tags: python, html, django

I am having some difficulty retrieving the user submitted data from the form. I am able to hard code a 'term' and successfully search the database, but with the current code I have now, I receive a MultiValueDictKeyError when the results are dynamically populated. So, I am wondering what approach I should use to handle the line: "term = request.GET['term']".

## views.py

```
    def search(self, request):
    try:
        r = requests.get(
            self.URL + 'company/contacts?childConditions=communicationItems/value=' + request,
            headers=self.Header)
        r.raise_for_status()
    except:
        print(r.text)
        raise
    return r.json()

def search_bar(request):
    term = request.GET['term']
    results = objCW.search(term)
    context = {'results': results}
    return render(request, 'uccx/search.html', context)
```

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.table_content, name='table_content'),
path('search_form', views.search_bar, name='search_bar')]
```

## search.html

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SEARCH</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="" method="get">
      <input type="text" name="term">
      <input type="submit" value='Search'>
  </form>
  {% if results %}
  Found the following items:
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>E-Mail</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for result in results %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{ result.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ result.lastName }}</td>
        <td> {{ result.company.name }}</td>
        <td> {{ result.communicationItems.0.value }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well in that case there is no `term` key in the querydict (`request.GET`).

Comment: GET query string parameters are usually optional, so your program should handle situations when they're absent. Try something like `request.GET.get('term', '')`

Comment: WillemVanOnsem yes, but in this instance, I am searching for a key I know to exist. @Ralf this throws a 500 server error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After handling the default case, which submits a null query, I was able to fix my issue. Below is the corrected code.

```
def search_bar(request):
term = request.GET.get('term')

if term:
    results = objCW.search(term)
    context = {'results': results}
    return render(request, 'uccx/search.html', context)
else:
    context = {'': ''}
    return render(request, 'uccx/search.html', context)
```